# What timescales do eddies operate at in the planetary boundary layer?

Tags: atmosphere, land-surface, planetary-boundary-layer, eddies

What are the largest eddies within the planetary boundary layer? What timescales do the operate on?

Edit: I'm talking about atmospheric eddies over land. So, eddies that are measured in [eddy covariance[(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_covariance), for instance.

Comment: @gansub: the way I've heard it used, mesoscale eddies usually refer to oceanic eddies. I'm talking about atmospheric eddies within the planetary boundary later, specifically over land. Will update the question to be more specific.